# args can't be resolved when I run program

Tags: java, static, system, program-entry-point, void

I want to run following code:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(args String[]) {
System.out.println("Watch on youtube: Mickey en de stomende drol");
    }
}
```

But I get an error. My editor doesn't give any compile errors. But when I run I get following : cannot resolve args.

Comment: I didn't realize the Dutch were into that kind of thing... Also, you appear to have your `args` and `String` backwards. Try looking at the [example here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t.aspx).

Comment: What do you mean with the dutch?

Comment: ["Dutch - detected"](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Watch%20on%20youtube%3A%20Mickey%20en%20de%20stomende%20drol)

Comment: doesn't matter, it's only output

Comment: [Do you google before asking on StackOverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
       System.out.println("Watch on youtube: Mickey en de stomende drol");
    }
}
```

Comment: o my god, what a horrible mistake. And eclipse fails to show this mistakes. Thanks man you're a savior.

Answer (score 3):

Valid main method signatures are:

1)public static void main(String[] args)

2)public static void main(String []args)

3)public static void main(String args[])

4)public static void main(String... args)

5)static public void main(String[] args)

6)public static final void main(String[] args)

7)final public static void main(String[] args)

8)final strictfp public static void main(String[] args)

Answer (score 2):

Because **args**  is not a type , where as `String` is

So it should be `String []args`

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String [] args) {// Placing [] before variableName is good Practice
System.out.println("Watch on youtube: Mickey en de stomende drol");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String[] args
```

or

```
String args[]
```

or

```
String... args
```

String is the type, not args.

Answer (score 1):

you do this either:

```
 String[] args, or String args[]
```

but you cant do:

```
args String[]
```

Remember, always put variable type first, the name doesnt matter, you can name it whatever, does not have to be `args`

Answer (score 0):

Like many of you said.
`String` is the data type. `args` is a `String` object.
So it needs to be:

```
public static void main(String[] args){}
```